# How can I remove combinations of groups specified in one data.table from another data.table [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, data.table

How can I remove combinations of groups (preferably using data.table in R) specified in one data table from another data table?

I could obviously loop this, but my real data is 10,000 plus lines and numerous groups so I'd like a more efficient method.

```
library(data.table)

baseframe <- data.table(
  group_a=c("a_1","a_4","a_3","a_1","a_2","a_1","a_3","a_1"),
  group_a=c("b_5","b_2","b_1","b_5","b_3","b_5","b_3","b_6"),
  group_a=c("c_3","c_1","c_1","c_3","c_1","c_3","c_2","c_3"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

removeframe <- data.table(
  group_a = c("a_3","a_1","a_3"),
  group_b = c("b_3","b_5","b_3"),
  group_c = c("c_2","c_3","c_1"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

desiredframe <- baseframe[-c(7,1,4,6),]
```

Comment: It is not recommended to have same column names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the column names and do an anti-join

```
setnames(removeframe, names(baseframe))
baseframe[!removeframe, on = .(group_a, group_b, group_c)]
```